# Determine $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{7}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

I have some problems to sove this limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{7}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\right)$$
I started with and lower and upper bound for $\frac{1}{n^2-n+1 }$. For which I determined on $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2-n}$. 
I want to use the squeeze theorem but how to go further. Because I have also a part in the counter $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Can someone help me with this. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please format your questions with mathjax

Comment: @Adri67 [Here's a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematical expressions on this site.

Comment: Are you sure this series converges?

Comment: This series diverges by the comparison test!

Comment: I have tried before to use mathjax but it didn't work. So that's why I used this way. Sorry.

Comment: Note that for any $n\geq 1$, we have
$$
\frac{n}{n^2 - n + 1} \geq \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac 1n
$$

Comment: In the middle of the question, you switch from $\frac{n}{n^2 - n + 1}$ to $\frac{1}{n^2 - n + 1}$. Which do you mean?

Comment: For the upper and lower bound I use the last one 1/(n^2-n+1). but you have also a counter part which is a summation from 1 to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{7}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\right)
$$
this problem is equivalent to determine whether this series converges: (and if it converges determine the limit)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}
$$
well since:
$$
\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\geq\frac{n}{n^2-n+n}=\frac{1}{n}
$$
and the series obtained by replacing the terms by a lower bound is this:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}
$$
which is the harmonic series with power 1, and it is **divergent**.
so the answer is:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{7}+\cdots+\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\right)=\infty
$$

Comment: thank you very much. But then I have a question in my workbook they gave as a hint to solve first the lower and upper bound for 1/(n^2-n+1) . So I don't now why we have to use then these bounds.

Comment: not sure Adri... indeed to solve the problem they are not needed or useful.

Comment: thank you very much again. This hint confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{n}{n^2-n+1}\gt \frac 1n$$ because it is equivalent to the obvious $0\gt 1-n$. Hence by the quite known  divergence of the  harmonic series,  the asked limit is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x}{x^2-x+1}$ has derivative $\frac{(1-x)^2}{(x^2-x+1)^2}$ and therefore is decreasing in $(1,\infty)$

Notice that $\int\limits_{2}^{n+1}\frac{x}{(x^2-x+1)^2}dx\leq\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k}{k^2-k+1}\leq \int\limits_{1}^{n}\frac{x}{(x^2-x+1)^2}dx$

We conclude:

$\frac{\log((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1)}{2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}((2 (n+1)-1)/\sqrt3)}{\sqrt 3}-\rho\leq \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k}{k^2-k+1}$

and

$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k}{k^2-k+1}\leq\frac{\log(n^2-n+1)}{2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}((2n-1)/\sqrt3)}{\sqrt 3}+\sigma$

where $\rho=\frac{\log(3)}{2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}$ and

$\sigma=\frac{\log{1}}{2}+\frac{\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Clearly the lower bound we gave goes to $\infty$